# AngularJS вывод iframe из json

Tags: json, angularjs

Есть список видео в json, где указано имя и url на iframe с ютуба.
Как правильней вывести, чтобы iframe корректно отображался?

вот мой код json:

```
{
"name":"Серия 1",
"iframe":"<iframe width='560' height='315' src='https://www.youtube.com/embed/8iWNE5_9d_U' frameborder='0' allowfullscreen></iframe>"}
```

вот разметка:

```
<div class="col-md-3" data-ng-repeat="seria in videos">
    {{seria.iframe}}
    <p class="text-center">
        {{seria.name}}
    </p>
</div>
```

вот собственно контроллер:

```
(function(){
'use strict';

angular.module('MainApp').controller('HomeCtrl', HomeCtrl);

HomeCtrl.$inject = ['$scope','$http'];
function HomeCtrl($scope, $http){
    $http({method:'POST', url:'json/mainvideo.json'})
        .success(function (data) {
            $scope.videos = data;
        });
    $scope.title = 'Главная';
};})();
```

Требуется вывести фрейм, чтобы он отображался как элемент, а не текст. Пробовал хранить только ссылку и вкинуть её во фрейм в атрибут **src="{{video.url}}"**, но эта конкатенация не работает корректно, пробовал с бубном танцевать **src="'+{{video.url}}+'"** но не помогло х(
может есть паттерн для этого?

Может это решается с помощью фильтров?
**ng-src="{{video.url}}"**
не работает, почему без понятия, может оно только для Img

Comment: смотрите `bind-html` и сервис `$sce`

Comment: спасибо, ознакомлюсь

Answer (score 1):

Для вставки сырого html на страницу в ангуляре есть директива [`ng-bind-html`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBindHtml), а так же сервис [$sce](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$sce)

Чтобы показать что данный html не нужно экранировать можно использовать метод [trustAsHtml](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$sce#trustAsHtml)

И лучше всего его применять сразу после получения данных.

В примере ниже для удобства был добавлен фильтр `trustAsHtml`, который просто вызывает соответствующий метод сервиса `$sce`

```
.filter('trustAsHtml', ['$sce',
    function($sce) {
        return function(html) {
            return $sce.trustAsHtml(html);
        }
    }
])
```

Пример:

```js
(function() {
  'use strict';

  angular.module('MainApp', []).controller('HomeCtrl', HomeCtrl).filter('trustAsHtml', ['$sce',
    function($sce) {
      return function(html) {
        return $sce.trustAsHtml(html);
      }
    }
  ]);

  HomeCtrl.$inject = ['$scope', '$http'];

  function HomeCtrl($scope, $http) {
    var data = [{
      "name": "Серия 1",
      "iframe": "<iframe width='560' height='315' src='https://www.youtube.com/embed/8iWNE5_9d_U' frameborder='0' allowfullscreen></iframe>"
    }];
    $scope.videos = data;
    $scope.title = 'Главная';
  };


})();
```

```html
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.js"></script>
<div ng-app="MainApp" ng-controller="HomeCtrl">
  <div data-ng-repeat="seria in videos">
    <div ng-bind-html="seria.iframe| trustAsHtml"></div>

    <p class="text-center">
      {{seria.name}}
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```